# Under which context does FirebaseCrash execute

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting

I have an APK and a test APK. when i invoke FirebaseCrash.report from the test APK, I get an message in the logcat that FirebasedCrash crashed with reporting a Crash. Since the FirebaseCrash.getInstance is deprecated. How do i make it run under the targetContext.

Comment: a test APK is for running instrumentation tests. Why would you want this to report crashes to the Live APK's crash console?  - You can report crashes if you want, but just create another firebase console for the instrumentation APK and treat it like a separate app

Comment: My test APK is automated and runs continuously on multiple phones. I collect some metrics from them. But yes, Let me try creating a separate Project or see if i can add the same project into Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. Just added my test package as another app under the same Firebase Project. the downloaded google-services.json contains info for both the main package com.xxx.app and the test package com.xxx.app.test .